# Parsing HTML with jSoup, then placing that variable within own HTML

Tags: html, url, html-parsing, jsoup, href

Okay, so what I am trying to do is a picture of the day type situation. 
I want to pull the top image from /r/Earthporn, have it display on a webpage (I will link back to the source), and pretty much thats it. 
I thought using jSoup to parse might be helpful and now I've hit into a wall. 
I need to find a way to parse out the html from the url source I give it, and then use that created variable to create an img tag in my own html outside of the script tag

Relevant code:

```
<script>
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/top/?    
sort=top&t=day").get();
Element link = doc.select("div.thing id-t3_22ds3k odd link > a[href]");
String linkHref = link.attr("href");

str="<img src="+linkHref+"/>";

}

</script>
```

After this it's all your usual html. I just want to be able to display the link that has been parsed out (here seen as linkHref) in the body of my html.
Not sure what I think I'm doing there with that str variable but I figured I would leave it in in case I'm onto something....which I highly doubt. 
I'm new into this jSoup parsing world, since the only other parsing I've done is with AS3, and that was an xml sheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never used jSoup, but if the only issue you are having is adding the `img` to your page, you can always just pick an element and insert the `img` tag you wrote as the `innerHtml` property. Ex: js- `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHtml = str;` and html- `<div id='myDiv'></div>`. Or you can also just add the `link` element like `document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(link);`.

Comment: What have you used? Is there something easier or better out there? I certainly want to learn as much as I can.

Comment: I've only ever used [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), but that's not to say that jSoup isn't capable of doing the same - I just don't know specifics about using it. Is the issue with parsing or inserting the content on your page?

Comment: My post here is about inserting, but as I realize now, after implementing your suggestion, that it is the parsing. I have begun working on a PHP DOM parser.

Comment: Why is that Java code wrapped in a `<script>` tag? Are you using JSP? That syntax makes little sense to me. How do you want to put the contents of `linkHref` into your webpage? Do you want to copy/paste it? Or do you want to auto-generate the whole webpage in Java? To the previous discussion: I think Jsoup is a really great HTML parser, CSS selectors are the best thing out there imo. Then again, if you can't directly build your webpage with the same application (like JSP/Servlets), it's useless...